# Rebuild Form Element with new property after Ajax

Tags: 8, ajax, forms

I want to rebuild a Form Item with new property after Ajax triggered on page, I try following codes

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

    if ($form_id == 'node_trends_form' || $form_id == 'node_trends_edit_form') {
        $form['langcode']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
            'callback' => 'MYMODULE_language_change',
             'wrapper' =>'edit-field-trends-wrapper',
            'event' => 'change',

        );

        $form['field_trends']['widget'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_route_parameters'] = array('lang'=>'test');
        $form['field_trends']['#prefix'] = '<div id="edit-field-trends-wrapper">';
        $form['field_trends']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    }

}

/**
 * Ajax callback.
 */

function MYMODULE_language_change(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
            $form['field_trends']['widget'][0]['value']['#title'] = "New Title After Ajax";

        $form['field_trends']['widget'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_route_parameters'] = array('lang'=>'onajax');
        return $form['field_trends'];
}
```

**Update :** in order to find the problem I change the code to simplest manner,
[image]

**The Problem is**  when ajax triggered  autocomplete replaced but changing on `#autocomplete_route_parameters` to applied !!!

**Update 2** Strange things is I try to change field title on ajax callback handler **it applied** and after ajax new title is **New Title After Ajax** but  autocomplete parameters not changed. I confused

Comment: Do you want to change the html on the page? Because for that you will need to use a wrapper.

Comment: Even if you don't want to change a thing on the page, you should try using a wrapper just to check if it helps.

Comment: @Eyal No, I want to change `#autocomplete_route_parameters` of autocomplete field. it's not related to html markups

Comment: The route parameters do affect the HTML output. They are used to create the autocomplete URL, used by the client side.

Comment: @Eyal can you tell me how can I  change It after language ajaxly changed?

Comment: Look under wrapper in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x

Comment: @Eyal thanks for your attention, I know now can replace a markup with new ones, but if seems this property can't changeable with with ajax.
can you try it and provide a snippet for me?

Comment: @zhilevan, Eyal is right, you need to define a wrapper, before you can debug this any further. What you a trying to do is ajax in ajax. This can get quite messy. First you need to check if the new form rebuilt contains the new process parameters. Then you need to check, if on the client side the code to implement this in the dom is running again.

Comment: @4k4 I add a wrapper for ajax, and return `field_trends` on ajax handler but still not applied, any idea?

Comment: Try to change field_trends in form_alter so that the form builder can process the new autocomplete parameter. And add the wrapper to the field `$form['field_trends']['#prefix'] = '<div id="edit-field-trends-wrapper">'` and `$form['field_trends']['#suffix'] = '</div>'` and then you need some luck, that ajax will rerun the autocomplete code.

Comment: @4k4 this id `edit-field-trends-wrapper` exist in first time, but I should add it anytime to existing everytimes, any way, I add this wrapper to `trends` field, after each times language changes `field_trends` reubilded but still autocomplete query variables is the same, anything else ? :(

Comment: Change the autocomplete parameter in the field only in form_alter. I think there is some process code that needs to be run by the form builder after form_alter and before the ajax callback. But I'm still not sure, if this works in the client.

Comment: @4k4 I tried to change title in ajax handler, it applied but autocomplete params not applied. I update question with more details.

Comment: Title is no problem, but a lot of things need to be processed in some way or another by the form builder. Better make all changes to $form in form_alter.

Comment: @4k4 finally I didn't understand why, I solve it with manipulate field on form_alter :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I achieve it with following, *Change autocomplete parameters prperty in form alter on rebuild event INSTEAD of changing property worked for me*,

```
    use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

    function zeytondev_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

        if ($form_id == 'node_trends_form' || $form_id == 'node_trends_edit_form') {
            $form['langcode']['widget'][0]['value']['#ajax'] = array(
                'callback' => 'zeytondev_language_change',
                'wrapper' =>'mtrend-wrapper',
                'event' => 'change',

            );

            //kint( $form['field_trends']);
            $form['field_trends']['#prefix'] = '<div id="mtrend-wrapper">';
            $form['field_trends']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
            $langcode = $form_state->getValue('langcode');
            if($langcode) {
                $langcode = $form_state->getValue('langcode');
                $langcode = $langcode[0]['value'];
            }
            else {
                $langcode = 'en';
            }
            //var_dump($langcode);
            $form['field_trends']['widget'][0]['value']['#autocomplete_route_parameters'] = array('lang'=>$langcode);
        }

    }


    function zeytondev_language_change(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
        $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
        return ($form['field_trends']);
    }
```

Comment: Yep. Anything modifying the form structure has to occur in the builder. Its tricky.